# Powershell where-object not playing well with PSdrive

Tags: performance, powershell

I'm trying to exclude two drives from a file search.  I'm getting an error when running the code: "Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles...'".  The search shouldn't touch C.  Help!!  What am I doing wrong?  Code attached.

```bsh
$Drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | where { -not ('c','u' -eq $_.name) }

$FS='(.*18)\.FOO'

$FPath=@(foreach($Drive in $drives) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive.Root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $FS} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{$_.Name} 
})
```

Comment: Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "D"}

Comment: Thanks, tried your suggestion, still returns the error: Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\...' is denied, despite explicitly excluding "C".

Comment: Perhaps you have a shortcut or [symbolic link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) in one of the accepted drives pointing to C ? Add a `Write-Host "Checking drive $($drive)"` just before the Get-Childitem in your loop to see what drive causes this. I would also advise to use parameters `-Filter '*.foo'` and `-File` to the Get-ChildItem.

Comment: @Theo Thanks for the tip. The empty cdrom drive bay throws this error.  When I exclude the cdrom in the file search, the "c:\ drive" error goes away.  Now to figure out how to exclude one or more cdrom(s) programatically.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | 
    Where-Object {"c","u" -notcontains $_.name} |
    ForEach-Object{
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse | 
        Where-Object {$_.Name -match '(.*18)\.FOO'} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        select Name 
    }
```

Seems based on your comments you are still getting the error. Lets trouble shoot it a bit. Lets output the drive that it really seems to error on.

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |
    Where-Object {"c","u" -notcontains $_.name} |
    ForEach-Object{
        $Drive = $_.Name
        try{
            Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse | 
            Where-Object {$_.Name -match '(.*18)\.FOO'} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Select Name
        }catch{
            @{
                Drive = $Drive
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the code re-write, but same error is thrown pertaining to C drive as in original post. Perhaps I have to live with it, just wanted a better understanding why it is happening.

Comment: I would think maybe you have a network drive pointing to C:\ ?
When i run it on mine it doesnt have that issue which makes me think its not a command issue as so much the way you have your drives / network drives

Comment: Dont forget to upvote answers you like or mark them correct.

Comment: that's interesting.  All the drives listed in the Get-PSDrive command are fixed. There are no links to the folder that shows up in the error. I'm at a loss.

Comment: @silverspr Lets troubleshoot it. I added a extra code at the end. Can you tell me the drive that it errors on?

Comment: The empty cdrom drive bay throws the error. When I exclude the cdrom from the file search, the "c:\ drive" error goes away. Now to figure out how to exclude one or more cdrom(s) programatically. Thanks again

Comment: @silverspr don’t forget to mark my answer as correct. I am doing this internet points :)